# Xcode Interface Builder stuck on 'Use standard value' when adding constraints

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

When I add constraints using the 'Add New Constraints' menu in Interface Builder, if the view is touching the edges of the main view, the value is stuck on 'standard'. If I type 0 in the box, it just resets back to 'standard'. The issue started occurring today. I have tried clearing Xcode settings but that has not helped.

[image: example of issue]

Comment: Yeah, I've just realized I got the same issue. I don't know if it's a bug or done on purpose, but it's sure annoying. For now I just set the corret '0' value in the Size Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and has been fixed in Xcode 11.4.